# Communicate via I2C using an 8-Bit Bidirectional (TXS0108E)

Tags: i2c

I want to communicate through I2C between a Raspberry Pi 4 and an ATMega4809 (Arduino Nano Every or Curiosity).

Since SDA/SCL pins in Raspi Pi are 3.3V and in ATMega4809 are 5V I thought I had to use a logical converter, for which reason I'm trying to use an 8-Bit Bidirectional (TXS0108E).

The problem is that the logical converter seems to be quite unstable because when I have everything connected I detect on and off signal quite randomly. I'm using `i2cdetect` and setting up 0x18 as address:

With signal:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 18 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Without signal:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

If I wire directly SDA/SCL pins I have a stable connection. However, I'm afraid that using it directly I might damage RaspiPi pins that work at 3.3V.

**EDIT:** schematics:

[image]

Comment: You need to demonstrate to us that your wiring is correct.

Comment: @joan, added the schematics. Thanks.

Comment: The schematics show what you meant to do.  We need photos of what you actually did.

Comment: It is perfectly safe to connect an Arduino I²C to the Pi provided there are NO pull-ups to 5V.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And do you know if the Wire library activates internal pull-ups? I'm asking because I found [this](https://oscarliang.com/raspberry-pi-arduino-connected-i2c/) and some of the answers says that it does.

Comment: I don't know this "Wire library"; the Pi has on-board 1.8kΩ pull-ups. Incidentally that link you posted (which SHOULD be in your Question) is hopelessly obsolete!

Comment: Just to confirm - (1) If your pull OE low, everybody is in high z mode. (2) It might be a good idea to pull up/down unused inputs, just in case. (3) So perhaps try TSX0102, (4) Did you get your no brand tsx from eBay? I have some 30+ level shifter modules (yes, use modules, not chips, some old AF's modules may have a problem, so they changed tsx to tbx or opposite, I forgot) in my junk box, about 30% of them are not stable, or not even working. (4) use short wires, < 30 cm to start prototpying, / to continue, ...

Comment: (5) remove ALL other on board module/breakout pull ups in the bus, because Rpi's I2C 1k8 is strong enough, (6) I vaguely remember TI has another chip for I2C especially. Just brainstorming, not sure I remember everything correctly.

Comment: I vaguely remember 0108e is general purpose, for both open drain and push/pull, but 0102/4 or another is for open drain only. I think open drain only is better, and there is another TI chip (cheap modules available from AliExp), specifically for I2C. Again, just quick and dirty brainstorming.

Comment: I assume that before connecting to Arduino, you already have 10+ hours experience successfully trying Rpi with TSX/TSB0102/04/06/08 to other sensors (more than 4 different types), say, on the same bus. My 500+ Rpi I2C experience tells me that compare with UART and SPI, I2C is 5 times more problematic, and sometimes black magic. PS - one important tip I forgot, if you are using Rpi4, lower I2c speed down to ***50kHz, or even 10kHz***. You might have a pleasant surprise.

Comment: are you sure if you really want to talk to Arduino over I2C? UART is 10 times easier and 10 times harder to go wrong! :)

Comment: In case your Arduino and Rpi are far apart, say over 10 meters, you might like to try other tricks, such as using CAT5 twisted pair cable, using I2C buffer and extender modules etc. You might find more references on long wiring I2C tricks in some of my old posts: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1352447&hilit=i2c+twisted+pair+tlfong01#p1353049
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1352447&hilit=i2c+twisted+pair+tlfong01#p1352373.

Comment: You might also like to read my experience in using TSX0102/04 vs TSX0108. My favourite is TSX0104, because I can have two pairs of I2C wires to do swap testing: (1) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1352447&hilit=i2c+twisted+pair+tlfong01#p1353049
(2) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1352447&hilit=i2c+twisted+pair+tlfong01#p1352373

Comment: I might have mixed up some of the TSX0104 links. Sorry about that: (1) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=232411&p=1422940&hilit=tsx0104+tlfong01#p1422940
(2) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=227137&p=1405964&hilit=tsx0104+tlfong01#p1405964

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs! I want to use I2C because I want to leave UART free to program the AVR directly. I'm still a bit newbie in this field and I'm using TXS0108E just because it was one of the first I found from a google search. Do you think is ok to just don't use a logical converter? I'm using ATMega4809 as a slave and up to now, I get good results when I connect SDA/SCL directly.

Comment: @Miguel 14, (1) Well, Rpi4B has 5 UARTs on board, and you can always use USB to UART adapters/cables to get as many UARTs as you want. (2) I always recommend to use logical level shifter to convert Rpi 3V3 GPIO pin signal to 5V. If you directly connect Rpi I2C 3V3 signals to Aruino 5V I2C pins, there is 1% chance that "latching up" might occur and your Rpi might be fried, or has its life shortened. You might like to search "latching up" in this forum. Have a nice day. Cheers.

Comment: I used a 10k Pull Up (5V) and it the I2C finally worked for me.